# How to initialize Robots in a ArrayList using a for loop

Tags: java

I want to initialize all the robots in the ArrayList using a for loop. What should I put in between the brackets of the for loop?

I've already tried doing r.get(i) = new Robot(); but it says that the left handed side of the equation needs to be a variable. I am a beginner so I appreciate your help.

```
package _00_IntroToArrays;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.jointheleague.graphical.robot.Robot;

public class _01_RobotRace {
//1. make a main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //2. create an array of 5 robots.
ArrayList<Robot> r = new ArrayList<Robot>(5);
    //3. use a for loop to initialize the robots.
for(int i = 0; i <5; i++) {

}
```

I need to initialize all the robots, but I don't know how.

Comment: You've got an empty ArrayList. Yes, you're passing an int into the ArrayList's constructor, but that just sets the ArrayList's *capacity*, is not necessary, and does not add any objects. First, create a new Robot object in the for loop and add it to the list. That's it. Note that this is covered in most any tutorial on use of ArrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

`r.get(i)` gives you a robot if it already had been added to the list. But you haven't added anything yet. In order to add you need to use : `r.add( new Robot() )` inside your `for` loop. Then you could get `i`th robot using `r.get(i)`. I suggest to study [Java Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Comment: What does the 5 do in ArrayList<Robot> r = new ArrayList<Robot>(5);?

Comment: `5` gives an initial capacity to the list. Later even if you add more than 5 capacity is dynamically increased. Again suggesting to study collections before doing actual coding. It will help in the long term.